# What is the reason of socket reset

Tags: java, c++, sockets

I have the problem. My socket connections are interrupted and I cannot find the route cause.

There are 2 servers. These are 2 computers which are in different countries. The 1st one runs Java program which waits for the connections via socket. The 2nd server runs C++ program that connects to Java server and opens several sockets on one port. Next servers exchange by UTF strings via these sockets.

The problem is sometimes socket connections are interrupted. This is not a network or cable unplugged problem because 2 sockets can be interrupted but the rest 8 work fine. The problem looks the same from both servers. Each server has a thread that call blocking read() method and both methods throw an exception at one time. Java server throws the following:

> java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
>      at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>      at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>      at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>      at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(Unknown Source)
>      at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
>      at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)

And the C++ server throws the following:

> Error 10054 (Connection reset by peer.
>   A existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.) occurred receiving data
>   ERROR in CSocket::Receive(), Line 199

All the obvious hypothesis like 'one of the servers closed the socket' and 'one of the servers sent infinite amount of data' are already checked. There is no detected reason for the problem. Servers can work fine for 1 hour and then 5 sockets can be interrupted during 5 mins, next 0.5 hours everything fine, next one socket is interrupted, etc.

Please advice where to go to find the problem route cause. Thank you.

Comment: Use a debugger, break when the exception is thrown, examine the variables and step through the strack trace to narrow it down.

Comment: Maybe you can find a reason, we can't because there is no code shown. But on the other hand: This will also happen sometimes even when the code is perfect, so you need to find a way to deal with this anyway.

Comment: just look up similar issues on StackOverflow in the past. Error 10054 is Windows barfing on your Java server forcibly closing its connection, which you already know.  But from what I read you might want to check that you're properly pulling all the data off of your streams, `readUnsignedShort` in the trace.  Just look around.

Answer (score 0):

when the remote connection is unexpectedly and forcefully closed due to various reasons like application crash, system reboot, hard close of remote host. Kernel from the remote system sends out a packets with RST bit to the local system. The local socket on performing any SEND (could be a Keep-alive packet) or RECEIVE operations subsequently fail with this error. Certain combinations of linger settings can also result in packets with RST bit set.